# EXCEL VBA: Not Showing Full List in Combo Box

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to pull up the subscription plans on my table in a combo box. I was able to make it work but it's only showing 5 plans even if there are 49 plans I need to show.

```
Option Explicit
Dim tush As Boolean
Dim ching, i As Long

Private Sub btnFax87_Click()
ching = Worksheets("Subscription").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
boxSubF.Clear
For i = 2 To ching
boxSubF.AddItem Worksheets("Subscription").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Below are the screenshots of the information I need to have on my combo box and what information are only showing. There's no scroll bar or whatnot.

[SUBSCRIPTION PLANS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7oGK.png)

[VALUES IN COMBO BOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NMzY.png)

Comment: What is `ching` begin resolved to? Is it only going to 5?  Possibly brecause of the use of `CurrentRegion`.  If you just to `ching = 49`, does it list all plans?

Comment: Perhaps consider using this. `ching=Worksheets("Subscription").Range("A1048576").end(xlUp).row` Instead of what you have currently

Answer (score 1):

For things like this I always have a lot more success storing them in a table. CurrentRegion is probably returning a range you are not expecting. Try doing

```
Worksheets("Subscription").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
```

in the Immediate Window and see what highlights.

If you store the data in a table, you can access the range like this:

```
Dim DataRange as Range
Dim ching as Long

Set DataRange = Worksheets("Subscription").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
ching = DataRange.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

in your pic I see there's some active filtering on column "A"

this could possibly make not visible (not filtered) any empty cell, that would *stop* `CurrentRegion` last row just before the first one

in order to both prevent this happen and have combobox list filled with non blank values only you can code like follows:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Worksheets("Subscription").Columns(1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    boxSubF.AddItem cell
Next cell
```

Comment: @KeithRelopez: did you get through it?